# SIMD minmag and maxmag

Tags: assembly, floating-point, x86, sse, avx

I want to implement SIMD [minmag and maxmag functions](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/mag.html).  As far as I understand these functions are

```
minmag(a,b) = |a|<|b| ? a : b
maxmag(a,b) = |a|>|b| ? a : b
```

I want these for float and double and my target hardware is Haswell.  What I really need is code which calculates both. Here is what I have for SSE4.1 for double (the AVX code is almost identical)

```
static inline void maxminmag(__m128d & a, __m128d & b) {
    __m128d mask    = _mm_castsi128_pd(_mm_setr_epi32(-1,0x7FFFFFFF,-1,0x7FFFFFFF));
    __m128d aa      = _mm_and_pd(a,mask);
    __m128d ab      = _mm_and_pd(b,mask);
    __m128d cmp     = _mm_cmple_pd(ab,aa);
    __m128d cmpi    = _mm_xor_pd(cmp, _mm_castsi128_pd(_mm_set1_epi32(-1)));
    __m128d minmag  = _mm_blendv_pd(a, b, cmp);
    __m128d maxmag  = _mm_blendv_pd(a, b, cmpi);
    a = maxmag, b = minmag;
}
```

However, this is not as efficient as I would like. **Is there a better method or at least an alternative worth considering?** I would like to try to avoid port 1 since I already have many additions/subtractions using that port. The `_mm_cmple_pd` instrinsic goes to port 1.

The main function I am interested is this:

```
//given |a| > |b|
static inline doubledouble4 quick_two_sum(const double4 & a, const double4 & b)  {
    double4 s = a + b;
    double4 e = b - (s - a);
    return (doubledouble4){s, e};
}
```

So what I am really after is this

```
static inline doubledouble4 two_sum_MinMax(const double4 & a, const double4 & b) {
    maxminmag(a,b);       
    return quick_to_sum(a,b);
}
```

Edit: My goal is for `two_sum_MinMax` to be faster than `two_sum` below:

```
static inline doubledouble4 two_sum(const double4 &a, const double4 &b) {
        double4 s = a + b;
        double4 v = s - a;
        double4 e = (a - (s - v)) + (b - v);
        return (doubledouble4){s, e};
}
```

Edit: here is the ultimate function I'm after. It does 20 add/subs all of which go to port 1 on Haswell. Using my implementation of `two_sum_MinMax` in this question gets it down to 16 add/subs on port 1 but it has worse latency and is still slower. You can see the assembly for this function and read more about why I care about this at [optimize-for-fast-multiplication-but-slow-addition-fma-and-doubledouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30573443/optimize-for-fast-multiplication-but-slow-addition-fma-and-doubledouble)

```
static inline doublefloat4 adddd(const doubledouble4 &a, const doubledouble4 &b) {
        doubledouble4 s, t;
        s = two_sum(a.hi, b.hi);
        t = two_sum(a.lo, b.lo);
        s.lo += t.hi;
        s = quick_two_sum(s.hi, s.lo);
        s.lo += t.lo;
        s = quick_two_sum(s.hi, s.lo);
        return s;
        // 2*two_sum, 2 add, 2*quick_two_sum = 2*6 + 2 + 2*3 = 20 add
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't `minmag = blendv(a, b, cmp); maxmag = blendv(b, a, cmp);` do the same as your code while reusing the same mask?

Comment: @EOF, it's `maxmag  = _mm_blendv_pd(a, b, cmpi);` maybe I should have called it `icmp` instead of `cmpi`. The `i` for invert.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware. But you can *also* invert the blend by reversing the arguments...

Comment: @EOF, oh, good point! I read your comment wrong not you mine.

Comment: Can you give a brief explanation of what `two_sum` is supposed to do ? It doesn't make much sense to me at first glance. Is it for [Kahan summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm), or something like that ?

Comment: @PaulR, it's not Kahan summation. It's doing (double + double) to [doubledouble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format#Double-double_arithmetic) addition. It's like 64-bit + 64-bit to 128-bit integer addition but for floating point instead of integer: `s` means sum and `e` means error (I assume). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30573443/optimize-for-fast-multiplication-but-slow-addition-fma-and-doubledouble) and read the comments for why I'm interested in this.

Comment: OK - thanks - that makes more sense now - I guess I wasn't sure what the `double4` and `doubledouble4` data types were (I'm more of an integer/fixed-point guy myself ;-)).

Comment: @Zboson [This paper](http://web.mit.edu/tabbott/Public/quaddouble-debian/qd-2.3.4-old/docs/qd.pdf) describes a method to do doubledouble addition with only 3 additional instructions when you don't know which number is greater in magnitude. I can't say whether it's faster than the solutions here since the 3 extra instructions are adds/subs which would contend for the same execution units.

Comment: @Mysticial, thanks, that's one of the paper's I'm using. The `two_sum` function I mentioned uses six adds/subs. When you know |a|>|b| it can be done in three.

Comment: You can do an FP add on port 0 by using an FMA (multiplying by `1.0`).  Latency=5, so don't do it on the critical path.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I already tried that, it was not better. See  Evgeny Kluev's comment in Paul R's answer.

Comment: You said you only tried replacing ALL your adds with FMAs.  If dependency chains were an issue at all, then 5 cycle latency instead of 3 would be a problem.  Only about half of the adds need to be FMA to balance port0/port1 (depending on what ports the other insns use).

Comment: @PeterCordes, you're correct. I could tune it suing some additions with FMA instead of all. I have not done this. I might look into again later.

Comment: Try IACA to find adds that aren't on the critical path, and turn those into FMA, if you do get back to it.

Comment: @PeterCordes, good point. I was using IACA but I did not think to only turn the adds not on the critical path to FMA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an alternate implementation which uses fewer instructions:

```
static inline void maxminmag_test(__m128d & a, __m128d & b) {
    __m128d cmp     = _mm_add_pd(a, b); // test for mean(a, b) >= 0
    __m128d amin    = _mm_min_pd(a, b);
    __m128d amax    = _mm_max_pd(a, b);
    __m128d minmag  = _mm_blendv_pd(amin, amax, cmp);
    __m128d maxmag  = _mm_blendv_pd(amax, amin, cmp);
    a = maxmag, b = minmag;
}
```

It uses a somewhat subtle algorithm (see below), combined with the fact that we can use the sign bit as a selection mask.

It also uses @EOF's suggestion of using only one mask and switching the operand order, which saves an instruction.

I've tested it with a small number of cases and it seems to match your original implementation.

---

Algorithm:

```
 if (mean(a, b) >= 0)       // this can just be reduced to (a + b) >= 0
 {
     minmag = min(a, b);
     maxmag = max(a, b);
 }
 else
 {
     minmag = max(a, b);
     maxmag = min(a, b);
 }
```

Comment: That's a clever solution. I wanted to use the min/max instructions but did not think of this. Thanks. I'll give a try and get back to you.

Comment: Do you know what ports min and max use? I need to beat three add/sub instructions. Your solution already uses one add so if min and max still use port 1 I'm not sure it will be any better (but it's certainly worth a try).

Comment: I added to the end of my question the function `two_sum` which I want to replace with `two_sum_MaxMin` if it's faster.

Comment: @Zboson: According to Agner Fog's instruction tables, `MAXPD` on Haswell is `port 1, 3 cycles latency`. You could shift some work to `port 5` by `amin = _mm_min_pd(a,b); amax = a^b^amin`.

Comment: @Zboson: and you could shift some work to port 0 by using FMA instead of "add".

Comment: @EvgenyKluev, good point, I tried that last night using `fma(a,1.0,b)` but it gave worse performance. But I used it everywhere (for every addition and subtraction). Maybe if I use fma in some cases instead of for every addition and subtraction it will help.

Comment: I made one more edit (sorry) with the ultimate function I'm after. It's ``doubledouble + doubledouble to doubledouble. It needs 20 additions/subtractions. Using my implementation of minmag and maxmag gets it down to 16.

Comment: You provided a clever alternative to my solution. However, your solution is slower than the `two_sum` function. Also the bit-wise and instructions I think have a latency of 1 and don't use port 1. Additionally, your solution is a bit less accurate. I think that's because of the addition you do which can "carry" but I'm not sure. Nevertheless, I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: Re accuracy - I guess there might be an edge case when `a == -b` - I think think you're effectively using `|a| > |b|` in you test whereas I'm using `|a| >= |b|` - it didn't show up in my limited testing but it might be worth looking at in case it affects the final result.

Comment: @PaulR, I found a quicker solution to my double-double addition using these minmaxmag functions.  See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30573443/optimize-for-fast-multiplication-but-slow-addition-fma-and-doubledouble/30643684#30643684

Comment: I think I am doing `|a| >= |b|` (using `_mm_cmple_pd(ab,aa)`)

Comment: I just realized in my definition above I did not define what happens when |a| == |b|. There appear to be different definitions. The one in OpenCL returns max(a,b) or min (a,b) when |a| == |b| another definition returns the first argument. I guess I should ask a question about this. My code does the second case.

Comment: E.g. For a = -3, b = 3 should maxmag return a=-3 or max(a,b)=3?

Comment: It appears even the max and min functions in IEEE 754 2008 can be user defined e.g max(-0,+0)  can return the first argument https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754_revision#min_and_max